# How can I open a file read-only from command line with emacs/vi/vim

Tags: linux, command-line, vim, emacs

Is there a way to tell emacs/vi/vim (from the command line) that I want to view the file in `view-mode` or `read-only`.

I know how to open a file as read only if emacs/vi/vim is already running.

Comment: Note: if you don't have the write permission to the file, Vim will by default open it in read-only mode. Actually, I think it is easier to control the file permission than to provide a "read-only" way.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

For emacs:

```
emacs FILE --eval '(setq buffer-read-only t)'
```

There's no startup option to force read only.

Edit:
If you put this small function in your shell startup script (.bashrc for example) you can open a file read-only by typing `ev file_to_view`

```
ev() {
  emacs "$1" --eval '(setq buffer-read-only t)'
}
```

Comment: I wish I could downvote emacs for this.

Comment: To open more than one file, the "-eval ..." has to be repeated after every filename, otherwise only the last file in the list is opened read-only.

Comment: Quick n dirty hack to work with multiple files opened on the command line: `emacs --eval "(add-hook 'find-file-hook (defun make-read-only () (setq buffer-read-only t)))" file1 file2 ...`

Comment: See also [emacs FILE -f view-mode](https://superuser.com/a/1293797/568188) answer.

Answer (score 147):

vim -R filename

Comment: Works great but I accepted Trey's answer because I prefer emacs over vim

Comment: And all vim users take revenge by upvoting it to more than the "accepted answer" :D

Comment: Note: some boxes seem to have 'view' command maybe aliases to 'vi -R'.

Answer (score 26):

view filename

Basically vim in read-only mode; simples!

As hinted by comment, in case `view` is linked to plain `vi`, here are *bash* commands to first inspect situation and then fix it:

```
# non-destructive inspection
which vim
which view
ls -l $(which view)

# overwrite current view with symlink to vim, requires root
ln -sfv $(which vim) $(which view)
```

Comment: No syntax highlighting though.

Comment: @Nifle: There shouldn't be any difference in syntax highlighting. If your `vim` has syntax highlighting but your `view` doesn't, perhaps your `view` is a link to a minimal version of `vim` that doesn't have syntax highlighting compiled in. Compare the outputs of the `:version` command.

Comment: Reason why it "just works": Vim will actually read `argv[0]` to decide its behavior. It's a common trick; AFAIK sometimes GCC and Bash does this as well.

Answer (score 10):

```
vim -R <file>
```

allows writing with `:w!`

```
vim -c ":set nomodifiable"  <file>
```

Prevents the user from making any changes to the file in the buffer. But the user could make the buffer modifiable with `:set modifiable`

You could use

```
vim -c ":noremap q :q<cr>" -c ":map : <Esc>" -c ":set nomodifiable" <file>
```

to prevent the user from turning off the "nomodifiable", and allow the user to quit by pressing `q`. But, then the user can't enter command mode at all, which may or may not be what you want.

You could also open the file with the less command:

```
less <file>
```

To view the file in a vim-like environment but without the ability to change the file.

Comment: +1 for using `less`, although as @nxdrvr points out you can press the ___v___ key to open the file in editiable mode in `vi`

Answer (score 9):

Small follow-up to the accepted answer: You can alias this in your shell to reduce it to a single command. For example in bash you can put the following in your .bashrc:

```
emacsro() {
  emacs $1 --eval '(setq buffer-read-only t)'
}
```

(different shells will have different formats for doing this, but you get the idea)

I would have added this as a comment in reply to the accepted answer, but it didn't seem possible to have a multi-line "code" block in a comment, and (in bash anyway) the above code really does need to be on 3 separate lines.

Answer (score 6):

For emacs you can also use the *view-mode*.

```
emacsclient --create-frame --eval '(view-file "/tmp/EXAMPLE")'
```

or alternative inside a terminal:

```
emacsclient --nw --eval '(view-file "/tmp/EXAMPLE")'
```

Or you can use my [wrapper script](http://svn.computer42.org/svn/computer42-src/c42-utilities/trunk/editclient)

Answer (score 6):

To just view file without ability to edit:

```bsh
cat <file> | less
```

In `less` you can go to "edit file mode" by pressing the <kbd>v</kbd> key. But you cannot edit standard input, so piping the output of `cat <file>` to less, stops `less` from going to 'edit' mode on pressing 'v'.

For vim the same approach

```bsh
cat <file> | vim -
```

Comment: Thanks for the `v` suggestion. Nifty.

Comment: +1, but no need for `cat`. Just use `<FILENAME less`.

Comment: @Sparkhawk, `<file> less` would give an error, I'm assuming you meant `less <file>`, but as explained in the answer, when using `less` directly, the user could press ___v___ key and go into edit-mode. Piping `cat` to `less` stops this from happening.

Comment: @Sheharyar He meant output redirection. Maybe you are more familiar with `less < FILENAME`, which gives you "Cannot edit standard input" when you press *V*. Similarly with Vim: `vim - < FILENAME`.

Answer (score 6):

In emacs you can do

```
emacs FILE -f view-mode
```

Syntax highlighting is applied. It doesn't just open the file as a read only buffer. Some commands, such as I-search, are accessible without the control key in this mode.

Answer (score 0):

sending a file to std out, may be acceptable given the size of the file

```
cat <file>  # dump whole file to stdout
head <file> # view the first few lines
tail <file> # view the last n lines
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to discrad to anyone user answer here, but i would like to aadd some more info about `Read-only Mode` file. As per oreilly documentation [Read-only Mode](https://www.cs.ait.ac.th/~on/O/oreilly/unix/vi/ch04_02.htm) There will be times when you want to look at a file but want to protect that file from inadvertent keystrokes and changes. (You might want to call in a lengthy file to practice vi movements, or you might want to scroll through a command file or program). You can enter a file in read-only mode and use all the vi movement commands, but you won't be able to change the file.

To look at a file in read-only mode, enter either:

```
$ vi -R file
```

or:

```
$ view file
```

(The view command, like the vi command, can use any of the command-line options for advancing to a specific place in the file.) If you do decide to make some edits to the file, you can override read-only mode by adding an exclamation point to the write command:

```
:w!
or:

:wq!
```

If you have a problem writing out the file.

For further ref [here](https://www.cs.ait.ac.th/~on/O/oreilly/unix/vi/appd_01.htm)